# Oracle SUBSTR error for long string

Tags: sql

I am using SUBSTR method in SQL query but due to long string it is giving below error:

> ERROR:   ORA-01704: string literal too long.
>
> SQL: 
>   select * from table where
>   tn=SUBSTR('....LONG STRING....',1,12)

please suggest any alternate solution to allow substring on long string in oracle SQL query.

Thanks

Praveen

Comment: Suggestion: Cast it to a 12 character sting since you want the 1st 12 it will drop everything else... Depending on RDBMS... `Select * from table where tn = cast(longstring as varchar2(12))`

Answer (score 0):

The error message states that the string literal is too long (not a limitation of the SUBSTR function). Can you use a bind variable instead of a literal?

```
select * from table where tn = substr(?, 1, 12)

sql.setString(1, theLongString);
```

Or maybe even do the substring client-side:

```
select * from table where tn = ?

sql.setString(1, theLongString.substring(0,12));
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can put it in a table field or variable and use `SUBSTR` on that?

Answer (score 0):

If you must use a string literal then you will be bound to the 4000 character limit unless, as Thilo suggests, you use bind variables.

If you are dealing with data from a table, you can use a CLOB and DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR instead.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the very long string to variable declared as 'clob' & work on the 'clob' type variable in regexp_substr.

```
declare
v_clob clob;
begin
v_clob := '00102034334:1:11-JUN-13:1,00102034334:2:11-JUN-13:1,00102034334:3:11-JUN-13:1,00102034334:4:11-JUN-13:1,00102034334:5:11-JUN-13:,00102034334:6:11-JUN-13:,00102034334:7:11-JUN-13:,00102034334:8:11-JUN-13:,00102034334:9:11-JUN-13:,00102034334:10:11-JUN-13:,00102034334:11:11-JUN-13:,00102034334:12:11-JUN-13:,00102034334:13:11-JUN-13:,00102034334:14:11-JUN-13:,00102034334:15:11-JUN-13:,00102034334:16:11-JUN-13:,00102034334:17:11-JUN-13:,00102034334:18:11-JUN-13:,00102034334:19:11-JUN-13:,00102034334:20:11-JUN-13:,00102034334:21:11-JUN-13:,00102034334:22:11-JUN-13:,00102034334:23:11-JUN-13:,00102034334:24:11-JUN-13:,00102034334:25:11-JUN-13:,00102034334:26:11-JUN-13:,00102034334:27:11-JUN-13:,00102034334:28:11-JUN-13:,00102034334:29:11-JUN-13:,00102034334:30:11-JUN-13:,00102034334:31:11-JUN-13:,00102034334:32:11-JUN-13:,00102034334:33:11-JUN-13:,00102034334:34:11-JUN-13:,00102034334:35:11-JUN-13:,00102034334:1:11-JUN-13:1,00102034334:2:11-JUN-13:1,00102034334:3:11-JUN-13:1,00102034334:4:11-JUN-13:1,00102034334:5:11-JUN-13:,00102034334:6:11-JUN-13:,00102034334:7:11-JUN-13:,00102034334:8:11-JUN-13:,00102034334:9:11-JUN-13:,00102034334:10:11-JUN-13:,00102034334:11:11-JUN-13:,00102034334:12:11-JUN-13:,00102034334:13:11-JUN-13:,00102034334:14:11-JUN-13:,00102034334:15:11-JUN-13:,00102034334:16:11-JUN-13:,00102034334:17:11-JUN-13:,00102034334:18:11-JUN-13:,00102034334:19:11-JUN-13:,00102034334:20:11-JUN-13:,00102034334:21:11-JUN-13:,00102034334:22:11-JUN-13:,00102034334:23:11-JUN-13:,00102034334:24:11-JUN-13:,00102034334:25:11-JUN-13:,00102034334:26:11-JUN-13:,00102034334:27:11-JUN-13:,00102034334:28:11-JUN-13:,00102034334:29:11-JUN-13:,00102034334:30:11-JUN-13:,00102034334:31:11-JUN-13:,00102034334:32:11-JUN-13:,00102034334:33:11-JUN-13:,00102034334:34:11-JUN-13:,00102034334:35:11-JUN-13:,00102034334:1:11-JUN-13:1,00102034334:2:11-JUN-13:1,00102034334:3:11-JUN-13:1,00102034334:4:11-JUN-13:1,00102034334:5:11-JUN-13:,00102034334:6:11-JUN-13:,00102034334:7:11-JUN-13:,00102034334:8:11-JUN-13:,00102034334:9:11-JUN-13:,00102034334:10:11-JUN-13:,00102034334:11:11-JUN-13:,00102034334:12:11-JUN-13:,00102034334:13:11-JUN-13:,00102034334:14:11-JUN-13:,00102034334:15:11-JUN-13:,00102034334:16:11-JUN-13:,00102034334:17:11-JUN-13:,00102034334:18:11-JUN-13:,00102034334:19:11-JUN-13:,00102034334:20:11-JUN-13:,00102034334:21:11-JUN-13:,00102034334:22:11-JUN-13:,00102034334:23:11-JUN-13:,00102034334:24:11-JUN-13:,00102034334:25:11-JUN-13:,00102034334:26:11-JUN-13:,00102034334:27:11-JUN-13:,00102034334:28:11-JUN-13:,00102034334:29:11-JUN-13:,00102034334:30:11-JUN-13:,00102034334:31:11-JUN-13:,00102034334:32:11-JUN-13:,00102034334:33:11-JUN-13:,00102034334:34:11-JUN-13:,00102034334:35:11-JUN-13:,00102034334:1:11-JUN-13:1,00102034334:2:11-JUN-13:1,00102034334:3:11-JUN-13:1,00102034334:4:11-JUN-13:1,00102034334:5:11-JUN-13:,00102034334:6:11-JUN-13:,00102034334:7:11-JUN-13:,00102034334:8:11-JUN-13:,00102034334:9:11-JUN-13:,00102034334:10:11-JUN-13:,00102034334:11:11-JUN-13:,00102034334:12:11-JUN-13:,00102034334:13:11-JUN-13:,00102034334:14:11-JUN-13:,00102034334:15:11-JUN-13:,00102034334:16:11-JUN-13:,00102034334:17:11-JUN-13:,00102034334:18:11-JUN-13:,00102034334:19:11-JUN-13:,00102034334:20:11-JUN-13:,00102034334:21:11-JUN-13:,00102034334:22:11-JUN-13:,00102034334:23:11-JUN-13:,00102034334:24:11-JUN-13:,00102034334:25:11-JUN-13:,00102034334:26:11-JUN-13:,00102034334:27:11-JUN-13:,00102034334:28:11-JUN-13:,00102034334:29:11-JUN-13:,00102034334:30:11-JUN-13:,00102034334:31:11-JUN-13:,00102034334:32:11-JUN-13:,00102034334:33:11-JUN-13:,00102034334:34:11-JUN-13:,00102034334:35:11-JUN-13:,00102034334:1:11-JUN-13:1,00102034334:2:11-JUN-13:1,00102034334:3:11-JUN-13:1,00102034334:4:11-JUN-13:1,00102034334:5:11-JUN-13:,00102034334:6:11-JUN-13:,00102034334:7:11-JUN-13:,00102034334:8:11-JUN-13:,00102034334:9:11-JUN-13:,00102034334:10:11-JUN-13:,00102034334:11:11-JUN-13:,00102034334:12:11-JUN-13:,00102034334:13:11-JUN-13:,00102034334:14:11-JUN-13:,00102034334:15:11-JUN-13:,00102034334:16:11-JUN-13:,00102034334:17:11-JUN-13:,00102034334:18:11-JUN-13:,00102034334:19:11-JUN-13:,00102034334:20:11-JUN-13:,00102034334:21:11-JUN-13:,00102034334:22:11-JUN-13:,00102034334:23:11-JUN-13:,00102034334:24:11-JUN-13:,00102034334:25:11-JUN-13:,00102034334:26:11-JUN-13:,00102034334:27:11-JUN-13:,00102034334:28:11-JUN-13:,00102034334:29:11-JUN-13:,00102034334:30:11-JUN-13:,00102034334:31:11-JUN-13:,00102034334:32:11-JUN-13:,00102034334:33:11-JUN-13:,00102034334:34:11-JUN-13:,00102034334:35:11-JUN-13:,00102034334:1:11-JUN-13:1,00102034334:2:11-JUN-13:1,00102034334:3:11-JUN-13:1,00102034334:4:11-JUN-13:1,00102034334:5:11-JUN-13:,00102034334:6:11-JUN-13:,00102034334:7:11-JUN-13:,00102034334:8:11-JUN-13:,00102034334:9:11-JUN-13:,00102034334:10:11-JUN-13:,00102034334:11:11-JUN-13:,00102034334:12:11-JUN-13:,00102034334:13:11-JUN-13:,00102034334:14:11-JUN-13:,00102034334:15:11-JUN-13:,00102034334:16:11-JUN-13:,00102034334:17:11-JUN-13:,00102034334:18:11-JUN-13:,00102034334:19:11-JUN-13:,00102034334:20:11-JUN-13:,00102034334:21:11-JUN-13:,00102034334:22:11-JUN-13:,00102034334:23:11-JUN-13:,00102034334:24:11-JUN-13:,00102034334:25:11-JUN-13:,00102034334:26:11-JUN-13:,00102034334:27:11-JUN-13:,00102034334:28:11-JUN-13:,00102034334:29:11-JUN-13:,00102034334:30:11-JUN-13:,00102034334:31:11-JUN-13:,00102034334:32:11-JUN-13:,00102034334:33:11-JUN-13:,00102034334:34:11-JUN-13:,00102034334:35:11-JUN-13:';
select TO_CHAR (regexp_substr(v_clob,'[^,]+', 1, level)) from dual 
               connect by TO_CHAR (regexp_substr(v_clob, '[^,]+', 1, level)) is not null;                       

end;
/
```